# In which issues did Professor X let Scott down?

Tags: marvel, comics, x-men, messiah-complex

During the Messiah Complex, Scott (Cyclops) gives Professor X a dressing down and mentions several times he's let Scott down

- Left brother in space (Havok/Vulcan)
- Lied about the danger room
- Lied about Krakoa
- Let Scott's father be killed

I don't recognise any of these events, when did they happen?

Comment: http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Krakoa_(Earth-616)

Comment: https://roguewatson.com/2015/02/25/marvel-comics-final-thoughts-uncanny-x-men-rise-and-fall-of-the-shiar-empire/

Comment: http://goodcomics.comicbookresources.com/2010/09/22/top-five-lies-by-professor-x/

Comment: For the record, I'm not at all caught up on X-Men. Hopefully the links above will prove useful to anyone preparing to answer.

Answer (score 3):

- Left brother in space
- Lied about Krakoa

The mini-series *X-Men: Deadly Genesis*.

- Lied about the danger room

*Astonishing X-Men* vol. 3 #11-12. Collected in *Astonishing X-Men: Dangerous*.

- Let Scott's father be killed

*Uncanny X-Men* vol. 1 #486. Collected in *Uncanny X-Men: Rise and Fall of the Shi'ar Empire*.